# How to generate one raster layer from multiple binary rasters for input in MaxEnt

Tags: arcgis-desktop, maxent

I have multiple binary rasters (calculated from raster calculator) in ArcMap. Now, I want to convert them all into one raster. Mosaic and Composite tools of ArcMap seem not helping here. I am not sure how to proceed with this. Eventually I want that 1 output raster as an input in MaxEnt.

Multiple binary rasters:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/PV1dH.png
Mosaic output:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/hK0Xu.png

Comment: Are your rasters the species occurrence records or environmental covariates? Do they overlap and is your question about how to manage the overlapping parts?

Comment: Yes, the rasters are environmental variables taken from worldclim. I worked on those rasters by using raster calculator to get the habitat suitability. Total binary rasters are 12 representing 12 months. Yes my question was how to manage the overlapping parts.

Comment: Could you clarify what you meant by "Mosaic and Composite tools of ArcMap seem not helping here."? How are those outputs differing from what you want?

Comment: Presuming "all worldclim environmental variables are identical in resolution, extent, and projection", what would you like to see say a cell has value of 1 in both t8p8 and t7p7? Is it SUM or MAX or MEAN of the overlapping cells? As mentioned in @ycartwhelen's answer, Mosaic to New Raster would be an answer. You need to decide that happens to the overlapping parts. Have a look at https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/raster-and-images/mosaic-operators.htm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you have multiple neighboring (and in slightly overlapping) rasters that you would like to merge into one larger raster. Based on the comments, perhaps habitat for a migratory species?

I would suggest [Mosaic to New Raster](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/data-management-toolbox/mosaic-to-new-raster.htm) as that won't involve overwriting any of your existing rasters, and will let you choose how to deal with overlap (max, min, etc.).